# Simple Horizontal Progress bar in LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I was wondering what is the most simple way to make a horizontal progress bar?

I'm new at using LibGDX and Game development. If you can, could you also comment all the function of each part so that i may know for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to leave comment.
check below link:

- [How do I make a ProgressBar work in LibGDX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434570/how-do-i-make-a-progressbar-work-in-libgdx)
- https://github.com/Matsemann/libgdx-loading-screen

Comment: Doens't matter that you do not have enough reputation. It's a good answer.

Comment: answers like this will give you enough reputation soon